# Transforming XML to XML, converting attributes to elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm converting an XML file that stores all its data as attributes in the elements. This file has a lot of data I don't need, so the transformation is to extract the required parts.

Unfortunately I can't find a way to change the attributes of the old file into elements of the new file.

Current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<report Title="System Information for Windows Build  Technician&#39;s Version" computer_name="example" language="NULL" xml_version="1.2">
<software Title="Software">
    <page Title="Operating System" H1="Property" H2="Value" >
        <item Property="Owner" Value="Tom Smith"  />
        <item Property="Organization"  />
        <item Property="Workgroup" Value="WORKGROUP"  />
    </page>
</software>
```

My desired output would to be able to take the attribute of say Owner and Tom Smith and create an element:
    `<owner>Tom Smith</owner>`

Comment: Have you looked at XSLT. If not, do that!

Comment: @forty-two yes, that is what I am using to transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
    <xsl:for-each select="report/software/page/item">
      <xsl:element name="{@Property}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
```